# Crear section deformada

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="__full">
    <section class="__bg_border">
       ...
   </section>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podria lograr que mi `section` pueda deformar de tal manera que pueda quedar como en la imagen, esta usando polygon pero no es la mejor opción para este caso.